# Intersection Point in Y Shapped Linked Lists

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, traversal, unordered-set

Given two singly linked lists of size N and M, write a program to get the point where two linked lists intersect each other.
For the given input as :
3 1 2
3 6 9
10
15 30
The correct output should be:15
My output- 10
Please help me out to find what is wrong in my code

```
    int intersectPoint(Node* head1, Node* head2)
{
    unordered_set<Node*> list1;
    int output;
    while(head1->next!=NULL){
        list1.insert(head1);
        head1=head1->next;
    }
    while(list1.find(head2)!=list1.end()){
        head2=head2->next;
    }
    output=head2->data;
    return output;
    // Your Code Here
}
```

You can visit this link for better understanding of the question [click here](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/intersection-point-in-y-shapped-linked-lists/1)

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. The fragment you posted does not read any input so it is impossible to verify what it does with a given input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept of length of linked list. In Y shape, for linked list to have a common section, it should have same length. For doing so, first we will calculate the length of both linked list and then subtract the extra one from the larger one to get the linked list of same size. Now we can compare node by node to get common node.
Code for the above logic is-

```
int listLen(Node *head){
    int len =0;
    Node * temp =head;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        len++;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return len;
}
int intersectPoint(Node* head1, Node* head2)
{
    int len1 =listLen(head1), len2 = listLen(head2);
    if(!len1 || !len2)
        return -1;
    Node *temp1 =head1, *temp2 = head2;
    while(len1>len2){
        len1--;
        temp1=temp1->next;
    }
    while(len2>len1){
        len2--;
        temp2=temp2->next;
    }
    while(temp1 && temp2){
        if(temp1== temp2)
            return temp1->data;
        temp1=temp1->next;
        temp2=temp2->next;
    }
    return -1;
}
```